# Handlebar/erb templates and Ruby Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use Ruby in my handlebar templates, via *.handlebars.erb templates, however the Ruby helpers that work in all other rails view templates do not seem to work there. I'm using the 'ember-rails' gem, which handles adding handlebar templates to the asset pipeline.

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def foo_bar
    "boo"
  end
end
```

**foo.handlebars.erb**

```
<p>Build Date: <%= foo_bar %></p>
{{#if view.isLoaded }}
    ...
{{/if}}
```

**Ruby Error**

```
undefined local variable or method `foo_bar' for #<#<Class:0x007fa4fbfc6a50>:0x007fa4fddf9630>
```

How can I include app helpers in the handlebar erb files?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is to create an initializer that adds the View helpers to the assets context class:

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  include ActionView::Helpers
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/218)